# Render different tags from Jekyll plugin in same template

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Problem:
  Rendering QR codes for users in a Jekyll template keep the last QR for all users:

I have this code:

index.html

```
    {% for person in staff %}
        {% qr person.qr %}
    {% endfor %}
```

qr.rb

```
require 'rqrcode_png'
class QrCodeTag < Liquid::Tag
  def initialize(tag_name, url, tokens)
    super
    @url = url.strip
  end

  def lookup(context, name)
    lookup = context
    name.split(".").each { |value| lookup = lookup[value] }
    lookup
  end

  def render(context)
    page_url = "#{lookup(context, 'site.url')}#{lookup(context, @url)}"
    qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(page_url, size: 10) # Size increased because URLs can be long
    png = qr.to_img
    <<-MARKUP.strip
    <div class="qrcode">
      <img src="#{png.to_data_url}" alt="#{page_url}">
    </div>
    MARKUP
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('qr', QrCodeTag)
```

2017-09-01-john-doe.md

```
---
category: staff
name: John Doe
qr: "http://www.johndoe.com/"
---

John is really cool...
```

2017-09-02-maria-doe.md

```
---
category: staff
name: John Doe
qr: "http://www.mariadoe.com/"
---

Maria is really cool..
```

Now, when rendering the page it renders the
page successfully but keeping the same object (With the QR code)
for all users rendered on the same page (They must be on the same page).

I'm quite sure that the problem is that in some how I'm not deleting the old object when creating the new one or something related to a global variable not assigned correctly.

In this case, each user should have a different QR code but they have all the same.

Workaround:

If you add the tag in the excerpt you will have the qr code tag rendered fine.

Now is there anyone can explain why if you add the data in the excerpt like the below example it will render a different QR code for each user, but if this is added as a variable in the front matter will be the same for all (Will have the last one repeated for all)?

```
---
category: staff
name: John Doe
qr: "http://www.johndoe.com/"
---

{% qr http://www.johndoe.com %}
John is really cool...
```

Comment: Is the last example really working? or do you get an error when it is rendering? (`{% qr http://www.johndoe.com %}`)

Comment: It renders perfectly, the thing is that im only getting the latest QR for all users.

Comment: It is not suppose to work like that, `page_url = "#{lookup(context, 'site.url')}#{lookup(context, @url)}"`, will try to find the string sent in the context, so it will be looking for "person.qr", in the context, so sending a url, should give a error like this: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. Is it generating a qr code that is correct for the `http://www.johndoe.com/` url as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the actual fix:

```
require 'rqrcode_png'
class QrCodeTag < Liquid::Tag
  include Jekyll::LiquidExtensions
  def initialize(tag_name, url, tokens)
    super
    params = Shellwords.shellwords url
    @url = url.strip
  end

  def render(context)
    page_url = Liquid::Template.parse('{{'+@url+'}}').render context

    qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(page_url, size: 4) # Size increased because URLs can be long
    png = qr.to_img
    png = png.resize(120, 120)
    <<-MARKUP.strip
    <div class="qrcode">
      <a href="#{page_url}" target="_blank"> <img src="#{png.to_data_url}" alt="#{page_url}"> </a>
    </div>
    MARKUP
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('qr', QrCodeTag)
```

So, we parse the string and get the real value for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`{% qr person.qr %}` is passing the `string "person.qr"`, not the corresponding value.

You can do `{% qr {{p.qr}} %}`.